# How to use an Image as an option in a form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using the latest Bootstrap v4.0 beta, I am trying to create a form to create an account.

In this example, if I want the user to pick Male or Female, I am trying to use a image instead of a dropdown or radio button.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option style="background-image: url(images/male.png);">Male</option>
      <option style="background-image: url(images/female.png);">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have tried using it as a image class but it treats the image as a submit button.

Is there a way to select Male or Female button as a selector?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this type of form control you should use a radio button as the user is only allowed to make one selection.

You can do this quite easily by using radio inputs and hiding them using the bootstrap class `sr-only`. You then apply your images and styling to the labels

(I've added some random CSS to show when an option is selected so feel free to modify that to suit your needs)

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

label:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Please select gender
  </legend>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" class="sr-only" id="male">
  <label for="male">
    <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1688/web_blog/48/user_male_white_red_brown.png" alt="male">
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" class="sr-only" id="female">
  <label for="female">
    <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1688/web_blog/48/user_female_white_pink_black.png" alt="female">
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I am looking for